Do you need all coax splitters in house to be MOCA capable?
I recently purchased MOCA adaptors so that I can hardware my desktop in my bedroom but cant seem to get them to work. I know the devices themselves work because i connected them together via  coax and connected one end to the router and another to a desktop that got a wired connection.
My question is do all splitters in my house need to be MOCA rated? I am going to provide pictures of the coax splitters in my house that have been there since it was built.
I believe I purchased a MOCA capable coax splitter so that I can connect to my router and the adaptor which I will link below so someone can confirm for me since it does not say in the description it is but reviews say they work with them.
1/3 coax splitter in basement:

2/3 coax splitter in basement:

3/3 coax splitter in basement:

Amazon link to newly purchased splitter (pictured):


Aside - rather than spending money on coax cable parts; is it more cost-effective to install UTP ethernet cabling and keep your coax gear at the point of entry/router only ?

MoCA uses frequencies up to 1675 MHz, so it's best to use splitters that have been designed, tested, and certified to carry those frequencies well. Splitters that have only been tested up to, say, 1002 MHz, may still do fine up at MoCA frequencies, but there's no way to know unless you're a radio engineer with access to radio engineering lab equipment.
In general, cable amplifiers, like the one in your first pic, are often only designed for cable TV and can be problematic for DOCSIS and MoCA. The one you have seems to be DOCSIS-savvy, but not MoCA-savvy.
The 1:2 splitter in your second pic says "EMI -130 dB", which makes me think it was designed to filter out any signal from coming in one output leg and going out another leg. That was great back in the cable TV days before DOCSIS and MoCA, but it's probably pretty bad for DOCSIS and especially bad for MoCA. (See comment from @user71659)
In general, avoid using splitters you don't need. It seems like you have enough splitters for at least 12 coax outlets. If those aren't all in use, consider disconnecting the cables that aren't in use and using smaller splitters so that only the outlets you need are live. Be sure to label your outlets and cables well so that you remember how to get the right thing hooked back up again if you want to make a certain outlet live again.
Also, be sure to install a MoCA point-of-entry filter between the line from your Cable TV / DOCSIS provider and the first splitter on your premises. It's not just for security/privacy of your MoCA network, and it's not just so your MoCA signals don't cause problems for your Cable TV / DOCSIS provider; it's also so that it can reflect your MoCA signals back down other branches of your coax cable tree, which helps your MoCA signals traverse your coax tree from one MoCA device to another.

"EMI -130 dB" is the signal leakage. Low leakage (very negative) prevents ingress into the cable system from transmitters like cell phones, and leakage is limited by government regulators to prevent electromagnetic interference to other spectrum users. -130 dB is easy to get because the whole case is soldered metal.

@user71659 Thanks, that makes sense. Edited.
